# Problems with AVAudioPlayer in multiView app

Tags: xcode, avaudioplayer

In my app i have 2 views: in 1-st there is a a tableview with audio-files. When to touch cell AVAudioPlayer begin play. When i go to 2-nd view AVAudioPlayer continue playing and when i return to 1-st view continue playing so. But from this moment begin problems: when i touch other cell begin play this track and previous and when i again touch play 3 tracks at the same time. And so my button "Play/Pause" works after that incorrect. How can i resolve this bug ? In every viewDidLoad  i create new object of AVAudioPlayer and assign a value to it of previous object

```
(void)viewDidLoad {

    [self.traxbax.avAudioPlayer stop];

    audioPlayer=self.traxbax.avAudioPlayer;

    [self.traxbax.avAudioPlayer release];

    [audioPlayer play];
}


(void)viewDidLoad
{

    [self.bmvc.audioPlayer stop];

    avAudioPlayer=self.bmvc.audioPlayer;

    [self.bmvc.audioPlayer release];

    [avAudioPlayer play];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is definitely some trouble with release of AVAudioPlayer. You can try to add in the after releasing line:

```
self.bmvc.audioPlayer = nil;
```

BTW: Not much understand why you have [super viewDidLoad] at the last line. It suppose to be first line of the method.